# Arabic number to Roman Numeral Converter: Number containing 4 will not convert

Tags: python, python-3.x, roman-numerals

Numbers that do not contain 4 convert just fine, but once number that contain 4 is tested, it does not convert properly.

I am new to python and I am struggling to see what was wrong in the code. The code for converting Arabic number to Roman numerals work for numbers that does not contain 4 in them. I have tried to test with different combination of numbers. The codes before the one below pretty much determine how many thousands, five hundreds, hundreds, etc that is in the number inputted. Could anyone help me?

```
def display_roman(M, D, C, L, X, V, I):

    CM = 0
    CD = 0
    XC = 0
    XL = 0
    IX = 0
    IV = 0

    if D == 2:
        M += 1
        D -= 2
    elif L == 2:
        C += 1
        L -= 2
    elif V == 2:
        X += 1
        V -= 2

    if V == 1 and I == 4:
        V = 0
        I = 0
        IX = 1
    elif I == 4:
        I == 0
        IV == 1
    if X == 4:
        X == 0
        XL == 1
    if L == 1 and X == 4:
        L == 0
        X == 0
        XC == 1
    if C == 4:
        C == 0
        CD == 1
    if D == 1 and C == 4:
        D == 0
        C == 0
        CM == 1

    print("The roman numeral of your number is: ")
    print("M" * M, "CM" * CM, "D" * D, "CD" * CD, "C" * C,"XC" * XC, "L" * L, "XL" * XL, "X" * X, "IX" * IX, "V" * V, "IV" * IV, "I" * I)
```

If I input numbers like 4 or 14, I expect to get IV and XIV respectively. But the actual outputs are IIII and XIIII respectively.

Please help. I'm sorry if there is something wrong with the format of my question as I am also new to stackoverflow. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you calling this function? It seems to me you have an implementation problem: there is no way to differ `IV` from `VI`.

Comment: You seem to be using `==` instead of `=` in your later assignments; that's not going to help your cause.  And that breakdown starts with the actions after the `I == 4` test.

Comment: This is how I call the functions: M, D, C, L, X, V, I = split_number(number)
 display_roman(M, D, C, L, X, V, I). Number is the variable that contains the user input

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for pointing that out. I have solved the problem. It turns out the [==] is the problem

Comment: This whole algorithm seems to be rather misguided.  You should think about what happens if both `D` and `L` are given the value `2`.  And what happens if `D` is given the value `4`.  But even those are sideshows.  You don't normally break down the data like that, in my experience.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You mean like the number 1100 and 2000? I am just started learning python so forgive me if my code is quite inefficient.

Comment: Well, you don't show the code that breaks things down, but you code for the possibility of `D == 2`, but you shouldn't ever get that.  Since you think you can get a bogus value, what do you do with multiple bogus values.  At the moment, if `D == 2`, you don't check whether `L` is valid, nor whether `V` is valid.  So, those `elif` lines should be `if` lines.  Or the whole test is superfluous because the outside code can't get at this function.  Incidentally, there are 21 questions that can be found searching with `[roman-numerals] [python]` — those will at least provide alternative algorithms.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The code before this is basically dividing the user input by 1000, 500, 100, etc with the integer division to know what M or D or C is. Sorry for not showing it also in the question. I'm sorry for asking this kind of question without looking deeper into the questions asked beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SO!
The problem is the way you are trying to define and change your variables. For example, this piece of code:

```
   elif I == 4:
       I == 0
       IV == 1
```

should look like this instead:

```
   elif I == 4:
       I = 0
       IV = 1
```

`==` is a boolean Operator that will return `True` if two values are the same and `False` if they are not. `=` is the correct way to assign a new value to a variable. After changing this, all works as intended.

---

```
display_roman(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4)
display_roman(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4)

The roman numeral of your number is: 
       IV 
The roman numeral of your number is: 
     IX
```

Answer (score 1):

This converts any positive integer to roman numeral string:

```
def roman(num: int) -> str:

    chlist = "VXLCDM"
    rev = [int(ch) for ch in reversed(str(num))]
    chlist = ["I"] + [chlist[i % len(chlist)] + "\u0304" * (i // len(chlist))
                    for i in range(0, len(rev) * 2)]

    def period(p: int, ten: str, five: str, one: str) -> str:
        if p == 9:
            return one + ten
        elif p >= 5:
            return five + one * (p - 5)
        elif p == 4:
            return one + five
        else:
            return one * p

    return "".join(reversed([period(rev[i], chlist[i * 2 + 2], chlist[i * 2 + 1], chlist[i * 2])
                            for i in range(0, len(rev))]))
```

Test code:

```
print(roman(6))
print(roman(78))
print(roman(901))
print(roman(2345))
print(roman(67890))
print(roman(123456))
print(roman(7890123))
print(roman(45678901))
print(roman(234567890))
```

Output:

```
VI
LXXVIII
CMI
MMCCCXLV
L̄X̄V̄MMDCCCXC
C̄X̄X̄MMMCDLVI
V̄̄M̄M̄D̄C̄C̄C̄X̄C̄CXXIII
X̄̄L̄̄V̄̄D̄C̄L̄X̄X̄V̄MMMCMI
C̄̄C̄̄X̄̄X̄̄X̄̄M̄V̄̄D̄L̄X̄V̄MMDCCCXC
```

Note that integers greater than 9 million are represented by the characters that contains 2 or more macrons, which are very unclear unless they are badly scaled-up

Answer (score 1):

Done in 2 lines! (Has an upper limit of 4000)
Here's the code:

```
n,k = {0:'',1:'I',2:'II',3:'III',4:'IV',5:'V',6:'VI',7:'VII',8:'VIII',9:'IX',10:'X',20:'XX',30:'XXX',40:'XL',50:'L',60:'LX',70:'LXX',80:'LXXX',90:'XC',100:'C',200:'CC',300:'CCC',400:'CD',500:'D',600:'DC',700:'DCC',800:'DCCC',900:'CM',1000:'M',2000:'MM',3000:'MMM',4000:'MMMM'},int(input('ARABIC TO ROMAN CONVERTER:-\n\n>> Enter Arabic Number: '))
print('>> Arabic Equivalent:',n[(k//1000)*1000] + n[((k-((k//1000)*1000))//100)*100] + n[((k-(((k-((k//1000)*1000))//100)*100)-(k//1000)*1000)//10)*10] + n[k%10])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print("ARABIC TO ROMAN CONVERTER [1-3999]:- \n \n")
x=int(input("ENTER THE ARABIC NUMBER: "))
b=["",'I','II','III','IV','V','VI','VII','VIII','IX','X','XX','XXX','XL','L','LX','LXX','LXXX','XC','C','CX','CXX','CXXX','CXL','CL','CLX','CLXX','CLXXX','CXC','CC','CCC','CD','D','DC','DCC','DCCC','CM','M']
d=["",'X','XX','XXX','XL','L','LX','LXX','LXXX','XC']
e=["",'C','CC','CCC','CD','D','DC','DCC','DCCC','CM']
if x in range(1,1000):
    print(e[int((((int(x/100))*100)-1000)/100)]+d[int((x-(int(x/100)*100))/10)]+b[((x%1000)%100)%10])
if x==1000:
    print(b[37])
if x in range(1001,2000):
    print(b[37]+e[int((((int(x/100))*100)-1000)/100)]+d[int((x-(int(x/100)*100))/10)]+b[((x%1000)%100)%10])
if x==2000:
    print("MM")
if x in range(2001,3000):
    print(b[37]+b[37]+e[int((((int(x/100))*100)-2000)/100)]+d[int((x-(int(x/100)*100))/10)]+b[((x%1000)%100)%10])
if x==3000:
    print("MMM")
if x in range(3001,4000):
    print(b[37]+b[37]+b[37]+e[int((((int(x/100))*100)-3000)/100)]+d[int((x-(int(x/100)*100))/10)]+b[((x%1000)%100)%10])
if x not in range(1,4000):
    print("Error")
```

Comment: This is a simple and easy to understand code for the conversion of Arabic to Roman.